# How to say Qt3D load material.lib located near obj file

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt3d, qt6

`6.3.0 MinGW` Using `Qt3DRender::QMesh` to load my obj file:

```
Qt3DRender::QMesh  *planeModel = new Qt3DRender::QMesh(rootEntity);
planeModel->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/tu-154/Tu154.obj"));
rootEntity->addComponent(planeModel);
```

File load correct but i don't see textures:
[image]
It should be:
[image]

Using `QTextureLoader` says me:

```
Failed to load textureImage data using QImage
[Qt3DRender::GLTexture] No QTextureData generated from Texture Generator yet. Texture will be invalid for this frame
Qt3DRender::QMesh::Ready
```

What else might be right way here?

[Github](https://github.com/andr1312e/Plane)

Comment: Did you already tried to load the OBJ file with the SceneLoader? AFAIK QMesh only loads the mesh, not the material information.

Comment: Yesi tried before Qt3DRender::Render::LoadSceneJob::tryLoadScene(Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader::Status&, const QStringList&, const std::function<void(Qt3DRender::QSceneImporter*)>&) Found no suitable importer plugin for QUrl("qrc:/tu-154/Tu154.obj")
Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader::Error

Comment: I found answer, publich it here asap

Comment: You need to build Qt with `assimp` support in order to make `QSceneLoader` load 3D file formats.

Comment: @karlphillip i am using speclial class for it. Publish it my github